# How to insert data into mysql database using oops php5 concepts?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new for PHP5 OOP concept.
Please give some example source code for "How to insert data using oops concept?".I want to use pure php5 concept for this even in the connection.php page also.
I want to improve my knowledge. please any one help me....

I know below the basic concept

**insert_db.php**

```
                $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
            VALUES
            ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[age]')";

            if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
              {
              die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
              }
            echo "1 record added";

            mysql_close($con)
```

### connectio.php

```
          <?php
            // connect database  code
             $dbhost ='localhost';
            $dbuser = 'tomking';
            $dbpass = 'dsfds';
            $dbname = 'mydb';
            //connectivity of database
            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die ('Error Connecting to mysql');
            mysql_select_db($dbname);
          ?>
```

Comment: I suggest learning MySQLi instead of the obsolete mysql API in PHP

Comment: Just google with 'insert mysql data in php', you will get lot of examples for it.

Comment: @justin But i want to use class and all the php5 concept for this. Google is showing result same as above code...

Comment: [This PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) will show you how to use PDO, how to wrap it in a class is your own design decision.

Comment: if anybody have a small sample of php5 project for  inserting data into database(using pure php5 concept).  Then please forward it to my mail ->  ashutosh10g@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Mysqli` or `PDO` for using sql queries instead of directly pass variables to query.

This will cause sql injection when you directly pass variable to query

If you want to pass variable to sql query , you have to use filters for this

[filtering-escaping-post-data-from-injection-attacks](http://corpocrat.com/2009/07/28/filtering-escaping-post-data-from-injection-attacks/)

[PDO Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

[MySQLi Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

And this is all pure `PHP5` concept.

Comment: Don't use `stripslashes`. Disable `magic_quotes` instead and let bind variables take care of all filtering for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database_name);

if($mysqli->error)
    die($mysqli->error);

$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");

$query = "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('value_1', 'value_2')";
$mysqli->query($query);
if(!$mysql->error)
   echo 'do something';

$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
$sql = $mysqli->query($query);
if($sql->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['field_1'];
    }
}
$sql->close();
```